# Will Kafka retention will also partition Replicas also?

Tags: apache-kafka

In process of estimating storage needs for 3 node kafka cluster,when we define retention of 3days on topic with 1 partition having 3 replicas assuming streaming 1GB/day will it need 1GB x 3 Replicas and retention for 3 days  9 GB across 3 brokers..
or will it retention only 1 partition data for 3 days ie 3GB overall across all the brokers?

Answer (score 1):

Replicas are for each message, so if you have 1GB of messages hitting one partition of a topic with `replication.factor=3`, then that amounts to a total of 3GB

Note: There are internal topics like `_consumer_offsets` as well that should be accounted for (its retention and replicaton factor).

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response, that's good point to consider _consumer_offsets and their replicas, but my basic question is abt will the replicated partitions will they also be retained for 3 days? i'm assumption is only the partition that is leader will take part in retention not the followers..
if my assumption is right storage for 1GB x 3 replicas is 3GB + 1GB  x 3 days (retention) = 6GB  spread across 3 brokers

Comment: 3 days is not a hard cap. It is possible for data to exist for longer since only closed segments are deleted. For example, You produce 1.5 GB of data, then you have an unclosed 0.5 GB left after the 1GB retention is applied. All partitions are replicated. As messages are deleted from leaders, then followers do as well.